# Show/hide button in custom action bar layout for viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have four fragments in my app and I intend to use a custom action bar. Two of these fragments have buttons on the action bar. I have a `TabsActivity.class` that has a `ViewPager` loading the four fragments.

In my `TabsActivity` and all four fragment classes i have a method `setUpCustomActionBar()` that i call.

I call this method in `onCreate()` for `TabsActivity` and for the 4 fragments i call them in `setMenuVisibility()`

```
private void setUpCustomActionBar(Activity activity){

    ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom, null);

    RelativeLayout menupin = (RelativeLayout) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.rl_menu_map);
    RelativeLayout menufilter = (RelativeLayout) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.rl_menu_filter);

    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

        menufilter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        menupin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

For fragments i call it like this:

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
   super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);

   if (menuVisible){
       if (getActivity() != null) {
           this.setUpCustomActionBar(this.getActivity());
       }
   }
}
```

**actionbar_custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:background="@color/theme_light_blue">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/it_regionname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Region_defined"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/faq_arrow_down" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/rl_menu_map"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/menu_icon_pin"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/rl_menu_filter"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:src="@drawable/menu_icon_filter"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have **TWO** questions:

1. I have to copy and repeat this method in every fragment. Is there a way to avoid repetition of code?
2. In 2nd fragment i set `menupin` to be visible ONLY. In 3rd fragment i set `menufilter` to be visible ONLY. In 1st and 4th fragment no layout SHOULD be visible BUT when i load the `TabsActivity` i can still see `menufilter` layout on fragment1. I can make it disappear by going to fragment2 and the switching to fragment1. Seems that `setMenuVisiblity()` is not called for the 1st default fragment when activity is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can create class BaseFragment (and write setMenuVisibility here) -> then 4 fragments will extends from this class.
2. When creating fragment, it doesn't call setMenuVisibility method. Only when viewPager changes fragment (when we scroll viewPager), It calls setMenuVisibility. At first, the actionbar is shown with full view. So at the first time, from activity, I call to the first Fragment to hide those view on the actionbar and It work.

Comment: this really doesn't answer 2.

Comment: I'm sorry.
I logged and the result is different.
When creating fragment, it doesn't call setMenuVisibility method.
Only when viewPager changes fragment (when we scroll viewPager), It calls setMenuVisibility.
At first, the actionbar is shown with full view.
So at the first time, from activity, I call to the first Fragment to hide those view on the actionbar and It worked.